# Adding together System.Drawing.Points

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, system.drawing, mousemove

I have come across the following code that uses the constructor of the `System.Drawing.Size` class to add two System.Drawing.Point objects.

```
// System.Drawing.Point mpWF contains window-based mouse coordinates
// extracted from LParam of WM_MOUSEMOVE message.

// Get screen origin coordinates for WPF window by passing in a null Point.
System.Windows.Point originWpf = _window.PointToScreen(new System.Windows.Point());

// Convert WPF doubles to WinForms ints.
System.Drawing.Point originWF = new System.Drawing.Point(Convert.ToInt32(originWpf.X),
    Convert.ToInt32(originWpf.Y));

// Add WPF window origin to the mousepoint to get screen coordinates.
mpWF = originWF + new Size(mpWF);
```

I consider the use of the `+ new Size(mpWF)` in the last statement a hack because when I was reading the above code, it slowed me down as I did not immediately understand what was going on.

I tried deconstructing that last statement as follows:

```
System.Drawing.Point tempWF = (System.Drawing.Point)new Size(mpWF);
mpWF = originWF + tempWF;  // Error: Addition of two Points not allowed.
```

But it didn't work as addition is not defined for two `System.Drawing.Point` objects.  Is there any other way to perform addition on two `Point` objects that is more intuitive than the original code?

Comment: Side note: adding two points would be hack (similar to adding 2 DateTime objects) - while it makes sense to add size/length to a point, I have no idea how one can explain for example result of adding 2 points representing two opposite corners of a rectangle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) for it:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Point Add(this Point operand1, Point operand2)
    {
        return new Point(operand1.X + operand2.X, operand1.Y + operand2.Y);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
 var p1 = new Point(1, 1);
 var p2 = new Point(2, 2);
 var reult =p1.Add(p2);
```